# Proto-Buf Inheritance Issue

Tags: protobuf-net

I've got a 3 level inheritance graph.
ProtoBuf 2.0.0.611

```
QueryRequest
VenueQueryRequest
VenueQueryRequestV1
```

All marked with

```
[DataContract, System.Serializable, ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
```

QueryRequest includes:

```
[ProtoInclude(10, typeof(VenueQueryRequest))]
[ProtoInclude(11, typeof(VenueQueryRequestV1))]
```

When I call SerializeWithLengthPrefix for a VenueQueryRequestV1 I get "Unknown sub-type: VenueQueryRequestV1"

If I ADD (not replace) before making any calls

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(QueryRequest)].AddSubType(10, typeof(VenueQueryRequest));
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(QueryRequest)].AddSubType(11, typeof(VenueQueryRequestV1));
```

I get "Duplicate field-number detected; 10 on: Designertech.AzureServices.Messages.QueryRequest"
If I only add the second one, I get the same error, but with 11 instead of 10.

If I replace, I get the original error

Which makes it look to me like it should know about the sub-type

Am I potentially messing things up with a cast or something somewhere?
At the moment, only the base class has any properties declared on it.

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
IList<string> RequestedFields
```

This is driving me nuts.

As an aside, this is being used to produce messages to be fed into the CloudFX Azure Service Bus framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each level only needs to notify the **direct** sub-types:

```
[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(10, typeof(VenueQueryRequest))
Class QueryRequest {...}

[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(11, typeof(VenueQueryRequestV1))
Class VenueQueryRequest : QueryRequest {...}

[ProtoContract]
class VenueQueryRequestV1 : VenueQueryRequest {...}
```

Comment: Knew it would be staring me in the face somewhere.  Thanks a million.